# ¿Cómo leer archivos pesados en Python?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, jupyter, dataset

Estoy intentando limpiar una base de datos en 'jupyter' con 'pandas' pero al ser tan pesada al momento de procesarla con 'pd.read_csv()' se queda pensando mucho tiempo y al final no logra cargarlo y me obliga a cerrar el programa ya que es muy pesado el archivo... ¿alguien conoce alguna forma mejor de leer 'datasets' pesados en 'python'?

Saludos

Comment: Si pandas no puede con él, malo... posiblemente tu equipo no tenga memoria suficiente para procesar todo el archivo "de una vez". Pero dependiendo de qué quieras hacer es posible que pueda hacerse "por trozos".

Comment: Sería bueno revisar si la base de datos cuenta con algún tipo de delimitador (',', ';', etc), y si está en formato 'utf-8', o 'latin-1', etc.

Comment: perdon la ignoracia... en que diferencia si fuese utf-8 o latin-1??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es muy común debido a la capacidad total del equipo en donde se está realizando el procesamiento de datos. 
Necesitas tener un equipo con requierimientos muy altos para realizar ese tipo de trabajos pesados.
Las grandes empresas ocupan regularmente equipos que trabajan en la nube como AWS por poner un ejemplo. 
Por este tema tienes puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Preparar el programa base para que trabaje en tu equipo de computo en donde solo podrás trabajar pocos datos.
2. Rentar un servicio en la nube que se encarge de la infraestructura del equipo que se estaría rentando, alli mismo hacer lo que hacer con tu maquina; la diferencia es que te permitirá trabajar con un mayor número de datos o bien puedes realizar conexiones directas a tu base de datos.

Saludos.